# How to upgrade from HTTPClient to volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

In this class I am sending request to server asynchronously by extending AsyncTask using HttpClient, I have created two custom classes one for Uploading and Downloading of Images from the server, and other for sending JSON Object and array. Beside this I'm also able to differentiate the requests using **RequestTag**

**Can we also do the same using volley?


How can I upgrade to Volley from the HttpClient having same approach like in below class?**

```
package com.creative.projectmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
/**
 * server manager class. performs all server requests asynchronously
 */
public class ServerManager {


    final private String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://192.168.200.10/";


    public void login(String email, String password, int requestTag) {
        String url = SERVER_ADDRESS + "index.php?mobile/" + "login";
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", password);
        params.put("authenticate", "false");
        android.util.Log.w("My App", email + " " + password + " " + requestTag);
        AsyncHttpPost requestSender = new AsyncHttpPost(url, params, requestTag);
        requestSender.execute();
    }
    public void downloadImage(String imageUrl, int imageSize, int requestTag) {
        ImageDownloadTask imageDownloadTask = new ImageDownloadTask(imageUrl, imageSize, requestTag);
        imageDownloadTask.execute();
    }
    private class AsyncHttpPost extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private String url = "";
        private HashMap<String, String> postParams = null;
        private int requestTag;
        private String errorMessage = "";

        public AsyncHttpPost(String url, HashMap<String, String> params, int tag) {
            this.url = url;
            postParams = params;
            this.requestTag = tag;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            byte[] result;
            String resultString = "";



            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            try {
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String key:postParams.keySet()
                     ) {
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, postParams.get(key)));
                }
                android.util.Log.w("My App",nameValuePairs.toString());
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

                if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    errorMessage = "ok";
                    result = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
                    resultString = new String(result, "UTF-8");
                }
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                errorMessage = "Encoding is not supported";
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                errorMessage = "An error occurred";
            }
            return resultString;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if (errorMessage.equals("ok")) {
                sourceActivity.requestFinished(s, requestTag);
            }
            else
                sourceActivity.requestFailed(errorMessage, requestTag);
        }
    }

    private class ImageDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private String imageUrl;
        private int imageSize;
        private int requestTag;
        Bitmap image;
        public ImageDownloadTask(String imageUrl, int imageSize, int requestTag) {
            this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            this.imageSize = imageSize;
            this.requestTag = requestTag;
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                image = createScaledBitmapFromStream(inputStream, imageSize);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                //do nothing
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            sourceActivity.imageDownloaded(image, requestTag);
        }
        protected Bitmap createScaledBitmapFromStream(InputStream inputStream, int minimumDesiredBitmapSize) {
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream, 32*1024);
            try {
                BitmapFactory.Options decodeBitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                if (minimumDesiredBitmapSize > 0) {
                    BitmapFactory.Options decodeBoundsOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    decodeBoundsOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                    bufferedInputStream.mark(32 * 1024);
                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream, null, decodeBoundsOptions);
                    bufferedInputStream.reset();
                    int originalWidth = decodeBoundsOptions.outWidth;
                    int originalHeight = decodeBoundsOptions.outHeight;
                    decodeBitmapOptions.inSampleSize = Math.max(1, Math.min(originalWidth/minimumDesiredBitmapSize, originalHeight/minimumDesiredBitmapSize));
                }
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream, null, decodeBitmapOptions);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    bufferedInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of examples of how to make requests with Volley, so "upgrading" will mean rewriting your code in different way.

Volley, in my opinion is not the best library for HTTP calls, I would recommend you to try 
http://square.github.io/retrofit/
for loading images use http://square.github.io/picasso/ or glide. These libraries will help you make you code cleaner whit out boilerplate stuff.